# Append text to a text file that is on my google drive (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api, text-files

I uploaded text file to my google drive and I want to know how can I append text to that file using python and how can other people that have my exe file of that python file also append it (so it works for other people also). 
I put that file to have shareable link and with that link you can edit that text file.
I tried with urllib.request.urlopen but it says that it is expected str, bytes and not HTTP response.
With urlopen i can print what that text file contains but cant write to it for some reason.
Also thinking this should be done with pydrive but I don't know how.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, how about this? 1. In order to add the text to the existing text file in Google Drive, it is required to download the existing text file and add the text, and then, the updated text is uploaded as the update of the text file. For this, Drive API is used. 2. In order to make users modify the text file, it is required to share the file with the users as the writer. If you want to make users do it at each PC, users are required to use each access token. If these were not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Or, as another method, how about using Web Apps created by Google Apps Script. In this case, the text file can be updated by sending the additional content from each user without using the access token. Because the update process is run at the Web Apps side. [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) I think that this is the simple method for achieving your goal.

Comment: i will try that method with web apps

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you need a sample script, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked thanks to clarification and guidance from Martin Schere and Tanaike, thanks!
Appending the text is done with "\n" because I don't know any other way, but it works.

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth=GoogleAuth()
drive=GoogleDrive(gauth)

fileList=drive.ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
for files in fileList:
    print('title: %s, id: %s' % (files['title'],files['id']))
    if files['title'] == 'user_info.txt':
        files.GetContentFile("user_info.txt")
        update = files.GetContentString() + "\ntest"
        files.SetContentString(update)
        files.Upload()   
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pydrive is the answer. You should authenticate your app and then write the code to automate what you're trying to achieve. Then you should compile everything into an .exe file and you're set. Here's the doc: https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/

Comment: Is there any example of the code, I am beginner at coding, I got setup pydrive and google drive api and got json file in same folder as script I just need example of the code it would help a lot.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is a very specific task. You'd need to find somebody to help you do that.

Comment: What language do you speak?

Comment: English and croatian